# error when deploying site on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

So I just deployed my site to heroku. on local it is showing up fine. i created a new controller called welcome and with a view of index. i also updated my routes folder. now i'm getting an error message on my site
[site](http://limitless-cove-5100.herokuapp.com)

here is a snipped of my heroku logs where i think the issue is:

```
                        less-cov2012-09-08T15:58:07+00:00 app[web.1]:
                    2012-09-08T15:58:07+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /] miss
                    2012-09-08T15:58:07+00:00 app[web.1]:
                    2012-09-08T15:58:07+00:00 heroku[router]: GET limitless-cove-5100.herokuapp.com/
                     dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=978ms status=500 bytes=643
```

here is the entire log:

```
                    2012-09-08T16:09:15+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3
                    .2.1/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:15+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1
                    /lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:15+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpse
                    rver.rb:111:in `service'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:15+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpse
                    rver.rb:70:in `run'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:15+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server
                    .rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:15+00:00 app[web.1]:
                    2012-09-08T16:09:15+00:00 app[web.1]:
                    2012-09-08T16:09:15+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /] miss
                    2012-09-08T16:09:15+00:00 heroku[router]: GET limitless-cove-5100.herokuapp.com/
                     dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=6ms status=500 bytes=643
                    2012-09-08T16:09:21+00:00 app[web.1]:
                    2012-09-08T16:09:21+00:00 app[web.1]:
                    2012-09-08T16:09:21+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 66.241.75.198 at 2012-
                    09-08 16:09:21 +0000
                    2012-09-08T16:09:21+00:00 app[web.1]:
                    2012-09-08T16:09:21+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (Ac
                    tiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished):
                    2012-09-08T16:09:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activereco
                    rd-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:374:i
                    n `retrieve_connection'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activereco
                    rd-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification
                    .rb:168:in `retrieve_connection'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activereco
                    rd-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification
                    .rb:142:in `connection'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activereco
                    rd-3.2.1/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:67:in `rescue in call'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activereco
                    rd-3.2.1/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:61:in `call'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activereco
                    rd-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:443:i
                    n `call'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack
                    -3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupp
                    ort-3.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__3191546681124262833__cal
                    l__697506052572710704__callbacks'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupp
                    ort-3.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupp
                    ort-3.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupp
                    ort-3.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack
                    -3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack
                    -3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack
                    -3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack
                    -3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3
                    .2.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3
                    .2.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1
                    /lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupp
                    ort-3.2.1/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack
                    -3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack
                    -3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53:in `call'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1
                    /lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1
                    /lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache
                    -1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache
                    -1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache
                    -1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache
                    -1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache
                    -1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3
                    .2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3
                    .2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1
                    /lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3
                    .2.1/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1
                    /lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpse
                    rver.rb:111:in `service'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpse
                    rver.rb:70:in `run'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:21+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server
                    .rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:21+00:00 app[web.1]:
                    2012-09-08T16:09:21+00:00 app[web.1]:
                    2012-09-08T16:09:21+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /] miss
                    2012-09-08T16:09:21+00:00 heroku[router]: GET limitless-cove-5100.herokuapp.com/
                     dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=7ms status=500 bytes=643
                    2012-09-08T16:09:22+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /favicon.ico] miss, store
                    2012-09-08T16:09:22+00:00 heroku[router]: GET limitless-cove-5100.herokuapp.com/
                    favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=31ms status=200 bytes=0
                    2012-09-08T16:09:22+00:00 app[web.1]:
                    2012-09-08T16:09:22+00:00 app[web.1]:
                    2012-09-08T16:09:22+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/apple-touch-icon-precomposed
                    .png" for 66.241.75.198 at 2012-09-08 16:09:22 +0000
                    2012-09-08T16:09:22+00:00 app[web.1]:
                    2012-09-08T16:09:22+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (Ac
                    tiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished):
                    2012-09-08T16:09:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activereco
                    rd-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:374:i
                    n `retrieve_connection'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activereco
                    rd-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification
                    .rb:168:in `retrieve_connection'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activereco
                    rd-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification
                    .rb:142:in `connection'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activereco
                    rd-3.2.1/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:67:in `rescue in call'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activereco
                    rd-3.2.1/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:61:in `call'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activereco
                    rd-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:443:i
                    n `call'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack
                    -3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupp
                    ort-3.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__3191546681124262833__cal
                    l__697506052572710704__callbacks'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupp
                    ort-3.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupp
                    ort-3.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupp
                    ort-3.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack
                    -3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack
                    -3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack
                    -3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack
                    -3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3
                    .2.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3
                    .2.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack
                    -3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1
                    /lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1
                    /lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupp
                    ort-3.2.1/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1
                    /lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack
                    -3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53:in `call'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache
                    -1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache
                    -1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache
                    -1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache
                    -1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3
                    .2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache
                    -1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3
                    .2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1
                    /lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3
                    .2.1/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1
                    /lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpse
                    rver.rb:111:in `service'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpse
                    rver.rb:70:in `run'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server
                    .rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
                    2012-09-08T16:09:22+00:00 app[web.1]:
                    2012-09-08T16:09:22+00:00 app[web.1]:
                    2012-09-08T16:09:22+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /apple-touch-icon-precomposed.
                    png] miss
                    2012-09-08T16:09:22+00:00 heroku[router]: GET limitless-cove-5100.herokuapp.com/
                    apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=6ms status=
                    500 bytes=643
```

Comment: That part of the log does not have the error. Look for ruby stack trace

Comment: You probably want to post some actual code, that log message isn't all that useful if you've deployed some broken logic.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your [Gemfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler#using-bundler-with-rails-3) is having

```
 gem 'pg', :group => :production
```

As heroku run on Postgres and it needs the adapter.  If not add it and re- bundle and push your Gemfile and Gemfile.lock and re-deploy